# String verification for alphabets and symbols

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

How can i check if my string has got any characters(a-z) or symbols(#,@,- etc) in postgresql?

Comment: Use regular expressions.  The tilde `~` is the operator for this.

Answer (score 1):

Regular Expression (regex) example from my comment:

```
select *
from mytable
where my_field ~ '[a-z]'   -- any lowercase character
```

other examples:

```
'[A-Z]'  -- any uppercase
'[aeiou]'  -- any vowel
'[#@-]'   -- the symbols you listed -- put the hyphen last, otherwise it's range
'[A-Za-z#@-]' -- all letters and your symbols
```

The Pg docs on Regex are superb:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-matching.html